# How to show barycentric weight in this form?

Tags: numerical-methods

Barycentric weight is defined as :

$$w_j := \prod_{\substack{k=0\\k \ne j} }^{n}  (x_j - x_k)^{-1}.$$

For any $n$, let $x_j = j$, $j = 0,\dots , n$. Show that

$$w_j = \frac{(-1)^{n-j}}{j!(n-j)!}.$$

The only thing that I got is

$$\biggl( j(j-1)(j-2)...(j-(j-1))(j-(j+1))...(j-n)\biggr)^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just say this is an exercise in counting. Remember that $j$ is any integer from the index set $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$. Let us examine the two end cases $w_0$ and $w_n$: 
\begin{align*}
w_0 & = \frac{1}{(0-1)(0-2)\dots(0-n)} = \frac{(-1)^n}{1\cdot 2\cdot\dots\cdot n} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} = \frac{(-1)^{n-0}}{0!(n-0)!} \\
w_n & = \frac{1}{(n-0)(n-1)\dots(n-(n-1))} = \frac{1}{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot \dots \cdot 1} = \frac{1}{n!} = \frac{(-1)^{n-n}}{n!(n-n)!}. 
\end{align*}
Now suppose $j$ is some integer between $0$ and $n$. We write the barycentric weight as follows: 
\begin{align*}
w_j = \left(\prod_{k=0, k\neq j}^n (j - k)\right)^{-1} = \left(\prod_{k=0}^{j-1} (j-k)\prod_{k=j+1}^n (j-k)\right)^{-1}. 
\end{align*}
For the first product, performing a change of variable $y = j-k$ yields 
$$ \prod_{k=0}^{j-1} (j-k) = \prod_{y=1}^j y = j!. $$
For the second product, performing a change of variable $z = k-j$ yields 
$$ \prod_{k=j+1}^n (j-k) = \prod_{z=1}^{n-j} (-z) = (-1)^{n-j}(n-j)!. $$
Combining everything, we thus obtain 
$$ w_j = \frac{1}{j!(-1)^{n-j}(n-j)!} = \frac{(-1)^{n-j}}{j!(n-j)!} \ \ \textrm{ for every $j=0,1,\dots,n$}, $$
as desired.